# Finding pairs of cells in two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find pair of cells from `Sheet2` and see if they exist as pair in `Sheet1`. Where in `Sheet1` I have:

[image]

and in `Sheet2` I have:

[image]

If they match, I want to return 1, and 0 if they don't.

I have tried things like:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FIND(TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,A1:B1),TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$5))))
```

but this does not work properly. It returns `TRUE` even when it is `FALSE`.

I have also tried a different approach, but I cannot see they way to continue with the pair. This formula only matches one of the elements of the pair.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$5,A1),1,0)
```

Comment: @ImranMohammed I've read about it but I am a bit lost. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: `=N(ISNUMBER(FIND(TEXTJOIN("|",,$A$1:$B$1),TEXTJOIN("|",,Sheet1!$A1:$B1))))` try this once and it will return 0 for the first, second, fourth and fifth cells while 1 for the third

Answer (score 3):

I'd avoid concatenation because of possible false positives. I'd try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=--(MMULT(--(A1:B5=D1:E1),{1;1})=2)
```

Comment: looks good but returns a column whereas I only need a value. ie. 1 in cell C1 as it has found a match

Comment: @Manolete, you would return a column at all times if you plan to test all rows. What you can do is "hide" the zero. For example: `=REPT("1",--(MMULT(--(A1:B5=D1:E1),{1;1})=2))`

Comment: @JvdV would you clarify what you mean by "possible false positives" and where would be such a scenario? I have seen the `XMATCH` with concatenation quite often, but now you make me think about the convenience of such an option. Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeal, the problem is universal. Avoid concatenation if possible. Imagine two cells, one with 'AB' and one with 'CD'. Now compare this to the value 'A' and 'BCD'. Values are different but will result in a positive match if one just blindly concatenated these values. At least OP used a delimiter to limit the risk. I myself am still not a fan at all.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could try in this way, it works for me,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=N(ISNUMBER(FIND(TEXTJOIN("|",,$A$8:$B$8),TEXTJOIN("|",,$A1:$B1))))
```

---

You can also use `MAP()` function with `XMATCH()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F1`

```
=MAP(A1:A5&B1:B5,LAMBDA(x,N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH($A$8&$B$8,x,0)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this **array formula** in `Sheet1`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1&B1,Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B,0)>0,1,0),0)
```