# Identify and remove remove duplicates from three columns and keep oldest - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, maxifs

I want to identify duplicates that have the same "CustomerName" "ZipCode," and "DOB," and only keep the record with the oldest "Date."

For instance, below, I want to remove the second John Smith record as it is the newer record.

| TransID | Date | CustomerName | ZipCode | DOB | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5X42 | 04/13/18 | John Smith | 90210 | 11/23/87 | johnsmith@gmail.com |
| 7YC5 | 01/27/21 | John Smith | 90210 | 11/23/87 | johnsmith@gmail.com |
| 28N2 | 11/17/20 | Mary Jones | 56451 | 05/16/91 | maryjones@gmail.com |

I have attempted to use MAXIFS() with limited luck.

Comment: Sort your data on the date ascending, then use Remove Duplicate, making sure to include all your data and use the three column as the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by ranking by **Date** column within the same group, where the group is represented by the rows with the same primary key. In your case a combination of the following columns: **CustomerName**, **ZipCode**, and **DOB**. You can use the following formula in cell `A6`:

```
=LET(in, A2:F4,pks, INDEX(in,,3)&"_"&INDEX(in,,4)&"_"&INDEX(in,,5),
 dates, INDEX(in,,2), rnk, MAP(pks, dates,LAMBDA(pk,d, 
  SUM((pks=pk) * (dates < d))+1)), FILTER(in, rnk=1))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

The name `rnk`, ranks each element of the same group, assigning the value `1` to the oldest date. This approach doesn't require sorting the data, `SUM` calculation ensures it. So the output is presented in the same order as the input, just removing duplicates.

**Note**: In this case, there is no risk of false positives by concatenation (in the way it was built the primary key), because the delimiter (`_`) cannot be present in the dates or zipcodes. Check the comment section from @JvdV's answer to this question: [Finding pairs of cells in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74687228/finding-pairs-of-cells-in-two-columns). Just for fun, we can avoid using concatenation and keep the same approach, via `MMULT` to identify the groups (`grs`) for each row, where `grId` is the group id, in our case we have only `1`,`2`.

```
=LET(in, A2:F4, pks, CHOOSECOLS(in,3,4,5), n, COLUMNS(pks), dates, INDEX(in,,2),
 ux, UNIQUE(pks), grId, SEQUENCE(ROWS(ux)), ones, SEQUENCE(n,,1,0),
 grs, BYROW(pks, LAMBDA(pk, FILTER(grId, MMULT(N(pk=ux), ones)=n))),
 rnk, MAP(grs, dates,LAMBDA(g,d, SUM((grs=g)*(dates < d))+1)),FILTER(in,rnk=1))
```

Notice, this approach doesn't need to sort the input data.

Comment: What a great idea.

Comment: thanks, @VBasic2008!, the question recall me something similar I did for calculating ranks within groups

Answer (score 0):

### Remove Duplicates Based on Multiple Columns

```
=LET(tData,A1:F4,DateColumn,2,UniqueColumns,{3;4;5},Delimiter,"|!|",
    Head,TAKE(tData,1),Data,DROP(tData,1),rSeq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Data)),
    Sorted,SORT(HSTACK(rSeq,Data),DateColumn+1),uData,CHOOSECOLS(Sorted,UniqueColumns+1),
    jData,BYROW(uData,LAMBDA(uRow,TEXTJOIN(Delimiter,,uRow))),rIndexes,XMATCH(UNIQUE(jData),jData),
    rData,INDEX(Sorted,rIndexes,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(Sorted))),
VSTACK(Head,DROP(SORT(rData,1),,1)))
```

**Highlights**

- Write the constants to variables.
- Use *TAKE* and *DROP* to return the headers (`Head`) and data (`Data`) in arrays.
- Use *SEQUENCE* to return an ascending integer sequence in an array (`rSeq`).
- Use *HSTACK* to stack the data to it, to keep track of the order, and sort it by the date column ascending (`Sorted`).
- Use *CHOOSECOLS* to return the unique columns in an array (`uData`).
- Use *BYROW* with *TEXTJOIN* to return the concatenated (joined) unique columns in a single-column array (`jData`).
- Use *XMATCH* and *UNIQUE* to return an array of the unique row indexes (`rIndexes`).
- Use *INDEX* on the sorted data with the row indexes to remove duplicates (`rData`).
- Restore the initial order by sorting the data ascending by the stacked integer sequence column (1).
- Remove the column and stack the data to the headers (`Head`).