# Finding the min value based on the number of duplicates in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lambda, min

I am working on a file with thousands of lines and need to find the minimum corresponding value based on duplicate values in another column

| Brand | Model | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Toyota | Tundra | 20360 |
| Toyota | Corolla | 28502 |
| Ford | F-350 | 36555 |
| Ford | F-150 | 28963 |
| Ford | Expedition | 27585 |
| Tesla | Model 3 | 25812 |
| Mazda | Mazda3 | 22036 |
| Mazda | Mazda6 | 25875 |
| Mazda | CX9 | 58200 |

What I need to for the formula to look to duplicate values in column A, regardless of whether its a single value or 3 duplicates, and then return the lowest cost.

Final result of what I'm looking for

| Brand | Model | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Toyota | Tundra | 20360 |
| Ford | Expedition | 27585 |
| Tesla | Model 3 | 25812 |
| Mazda | Mazda3 | 22036 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel - extracting top 5 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639470/excel-extracting-top-5-values)

Comment: Hmm.  Perhaps sort by Brand and then Price descending.  Then write a formula that indicates when the Brand is not equal to the row above it.  Those are the ones you want to keep.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's worth adding an older-style countifs approach:

```
=FILTER(A2:C10,COUNTIFS(A2:A10,A2:A10,C2:C10,"<"&C2:C10)=0)
```

[image]

Will it be slow if OP has 'thousands of lines'? Yes, probably.

Comment: Definitely worth it. Other answers will be just as slow I suppose (if not slower).

Comment: Tried it on 10K rows, mine takes a second or so, yours is instantaneous.

Comment: Who would have thought, `LAMBDA()` keeps surprising me. Mostly slow, quick at times =)

Comment: I am surprised too, I tested it for 10K rows too: Tom (0.77s), JvdV (0.06), and mine (21s). I am using a `LAMBDA()` too (`MAP`) but it gives the worse performance.

Comment: Just for curiosity, I tested this one: `=LET(in,A2:C10,A,TAKE(in,,1),C,TAKE(in,,-1), ux, UNIQUE(A),m, MINIFS(C,A,ux),FILTER(in,1-ISNA(XMATCH(A&"_"&C,ux&"_"&m))))` is the fastest one. I tested for `100K` rows: JvdV(0.54s) and this solution (0.24s), the `LAMBDA` solution is incredibly fast anyway. To be aware of possible false positives due to concatenation, but not really based on the input data string pattern. I didn't test the other solutions, because the performance was lower already for fewer rows.

Answer (score 3):

One option:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=LET(x,TOROW(UNIQUE(A2:A10)),FILTER(A2:C10,BYROW((A2:A10=x)*(C2:C10=MINIFS(C2:C10,A2:A10,x)),LAMBDA(z,SUM(z)))))
```

Comment: Why `(y)` and not `y`?

Comment: @JosWoolley, typo I suppose =). Ill get rid of that whole variable. Not needed.

Comment: This really helped me today. @JvdV Sir.

Answer (score 3):

### Cheapest Car By Make

[image]

- Here's a `REDUCE` version. Hopefully, there aren't too many makes.

```
=LET(d,A2:C10,bc,1,pc,3,
    b,INDEX(d,,bc),u,UNIQUE(b),
DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(u)),LAMBDA(rr,r,
    VSTACK(rr,TAKE(SORT(FILTER(d,b=INDEX(u,r),""),pc),1)))),1))
```

**The Variables**

- d  - the data (range)
- bc - the make column index
- pc - the price column index
- b - the make column
- u - the unique makes
- rr - the current Reduce result
- r - the current Reduce row

**The Flow**

- For each make, the data is **FILTER**ed by the **UNIQUE** make at the row **INDEX** supplied from the **SEQUENCE** function, **SORT**ed, and only the first row is **TAKE**n.
- Each row is **VSTACK**ed to the bottom of the previous ones, the **REDUCE**d result, and finally, the initial erroring row is **DROP**ped.

Comment: This was fast when tested on 10K rows (I tried a similar approach with the the sort outside the reduce and the result was dismal, as we found previously).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option, it is based on ranking by price within each group (brand) *formula 1*:

```
=LET(in,A2:C10,A,TAKE(in,,1),C,TAKE(in,,-1),
 r, MAP(A,C,LAMBDA(x,y,SUM((A=x)*(C<y))+1)),FILTER(in,r=1))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]
**Note**: I changed intentionally the price of `Ford Expeditor` to the same lowest price of `Mazda` and also interchanged `Mazda3` with `Tundra` for testing purposes, to make sure the order by the brand is not relevant and that it ranks by group properly.

For illustrative purposes, here is the output of `r` (rank), so we can see how it works:
[image: rank output]

The good thing about this approach is that with minimal changes, you can change the filter criteria. For example to get the two lowest prices by brand, just filter by `2`.

If you want to rank by maximum price instead, then change `(C < y)` with `(C > y)`, so it is additional flexibility this approach has.

### Performance

See comments on VBasic2008 and Tom Sharpe's answers. The above solution (*formula 1*) for a large dataset of around `10K` rows, shows lower performance (`54secs`) compared to JvdV and Tom solutions (fraction of a second). Being JvdV the fastest one. I didn't consider VBasic2008's solution because we know from other questions/answers that `REDUCE/VSTACK` has a significant time consumption. Then I found the following approach (*formula 2*):

```
=LET(in,A2:C10,A,TAKE(in,,1),C,TAKE(in,,-1), ux, UNIQUE(A),m, 
 MINIFS(C,A,ux),FILTER(in,1-ISNA(XMATCH(A&"_"&C,ux&"_"&m))))
```

which is easy to understand and very fast. Concatenation may produce false positives, which is why it is a good practice to use a delimiter (`_`) that is not part of the dataset character set. Check JvdV answer (comment section) to this question: [Finding pairs of cells in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74687228/finding-pairs-of-cells-in-two-columns).

Later I found it is possible to avoid concatenation as follows with a similar performance result as JvdV's solution (but not better than the `XMATCH` approach) *formula 3*:

```
=LET(in,A2:C10,A,TAKE(in,,1),C,TAKE(in,,-1),ux,UNIQUE(A),m,MINIFS(C,A,ux),
 FILTER(in,MMULT(N(A=TOROW(ux))*N(C=TOROW(m)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(m),,,0))=1))
```

**Note**: If you look carefully at this approach it ends up in JvdV's approach, but using `MMULT` instead of `BYROW`, which may explain why both have a similar performance. I just added the comparison `=1`, but it is not really necessary.

Here testing result I did for `100K` rows:

| *formula 2* (`XMATCH`) | JvdV (`BYROW`) | *formula 3* (`MMULT`) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `0.24secs` | `0.54secs` | `0.53secs` |

Worth to mention that even using `BYROW` which is a `LAMBDA` function, that usually is more time-consuming, it is about double, but anyway really fast too.

Comment: This is also good solution, but i couldn't make out and had to use `Thunks` since I have two different data in different sheets.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya share your Excel file so I can take a look at it. Thanks

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I added my solution adapted to your sample data in `F12`, I don't see any difference from the solution in `F2`, other than different sorting (I don't change the order of the input data) and the empty price because it is lower (treated as zero) for Paracetamol Tablet.

Comment: Alright checking now